# FFmpeg command not producing desired video duration from image sequence

Tags: command-line, bash, ffmpeg, video

I have a set of 5 images and I want to use FFmpeg to create a video sequence from them. I am using the following command to achieve this:

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i '*_0[0-5].png' -r 25 -t 8 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

Based on my calculations, this command should output a video sequence that lasts 8 seconds, with each image lasting 1.6 seconds (or 40 frames at a frame rate of 25 fps). However, when I run the command, it produces a video sequence that lasts only 5 frames, with each image lasting only one frame.

I am running this command on MacOS using Bash.

Comment: IMHO you should add `-framerate 5/8` to make 5 images in 8 seconds

Comment: perfect, that solves it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add to command line `-framerate` this will make what you want. The command will be:

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -framerate 5/8 -i '*_0[0-5].png' -r 25 -t 8 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

This value (`5/8`) will ensure you have 5 "frames" for 8 seconds